# Arduino loops add clock cycles, why?

Tags: loops, arduino

It seems that on Arduino, using loops results in more clock cycles. The default loop adds about 4 cycles per iteration, any other loop (while, for etc.) adds 2. Thus, not using any loop at all, and instead explicitly typing in the repeats, results in fewer cycles. Why is that?

Here are some examples of what I mean:

**Example 1**

```
void loop() {
  for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    PORTB |= 0b00010000;
    PORTB &= 0b11101111;
  }
}
```

[screenshot of measurement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7qk7.png)

**Example 2**

```
void loop() {
  PORTB |= 0b00010000;
  PORTB &= 0b11101111;
  PORTB |= 0b00010000;
  PORTB &= 0b11101111;
  PORTB |= 0b00010000;
  PORTB &= 0b11101111;
  PORTB |= 0b00010000;
  PORTB &= 0b11101111;
}
```

[screenshot of measurement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA583.png)

**Example 3**

```
void loop() {
  while (1) {
    PORTB |= 0b00010000;
    PORTB &= 0b11101111;
    PORTB |= 0b00010000;
    PORTB &= 0b11101111;
    PORTB |= 0b00010000;
    PORTB &= 0b11101111;
    PORTB |= 0b00010000;
    PORTB &= 0b11101111;
  }
}
```

[screenshot of measurement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxLn6.png)

Answer (score 0):

The simple story is:

In this case, example 2 and 3 are the same (and usually the compiler optimize the code and remove useless instructions). Those examples have only 2 instructions:

1. PORTB |= 0b00010000;
2. PORTB &= 0b11101111;

**Conclusion** for those example the code only change the port value

For example 1 you have 5 instructions (1 once per for and 4 for each iteration):

1. int i = 0 (once per for)
2. i < 4
3. PORTB |= 0b00010000;
4. PORTB &= 0b11101111;
5. i++

**Conclusion** for this example the code change the port value and handle the for index

In order to understand why you should learn what a compiler does and how a processor works. Here is the assembly code for your examples

Example 1

```
PORTB:
        .zero   4
loop():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
.L3:
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 3
        jg      .L4
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        or      eax, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        and     eax, 239
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        jmp     .L3
.L4:
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Example 2

```
PORTB:
        .zero   4
loop():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        or      eax, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        and     eax, 239
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        or      eax, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        and     eax, 239
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        or      eax, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        and     eax, 239
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        or      eax, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        and     eax, 239
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Example 3

```
PORTB:
        .zero   4
loop():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
.L2:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        or      eax, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        and     eax, 239
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        or      eax, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        and     eax, 239
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        or      eax, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        and     eax, 239
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        or      eax, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR PORTB[rip]
        and     eax, 239
        mov     DWORD PTR PORTB[rip], eax
        jmp     .L2
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! Yes, example 2 and 3 should be the same but they aren't, so the standard Arduino loop isn't the same as a while loop for some reason? But you're saying it's expected to have added cycles from a while (1)-loop? I will follow your advice and read up on compilers and processors and maybe it all will clear up!